# merge different rows of a column into one row

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following `dataframe`

```
  column1 column2  
0 Paul       xx       
1 John       aa      
2 Paul       gg      
3 John       xx       
4 John       bb       
5 George     gg       
.
.
.
6 Jonathan   ff
```

I want to have the information of each person in one row. On the same `row` I want to have the `index` but in another `column`. So I want a `dataframe` like this:

```
  column1     column2   column3  
 0 Paul        0,2       xx, gg       
 1 John        1,3,4     aa, xx, bb             
 5 George      5         gg       
 .
 .
 .
 n Jonathan    n         ff
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the index to a column using `.reset_index()`, then group by `column1`, and aggregate to a list.

```
df2 = df.reset_index().groupby('column1').agg(list).reset_index()
df2
# returns:
  column1      index       column2
0  George        [5]          [gg]
1    John  [1, 3, 4]  [aa, xx, bb]
2    Paul     [0, 2]      [xx, gg]
```

To reorder the results and set the index as in the example, you can use:

```
ix = pd.Index(df2['index'].str.get(0)).rename(None)
df3 = df2.set_index(ix).sort_index()
df3
# returns:
      column1      index       column2
0        Paul     [0, 2]      [xx, gg]
1        John  [1, 3, 4]  [aa, xx, bb]
5      George        [5]          [gg]
```

Comment: is it possible to have the information presented as in the first dataframe. So first Paul then John then George. Also is it a good practice to have the values of a column into a list?

Comment: Sure, see my updated answer